# Question about sufficient statistic / MLE (conformation)

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello I have always been a bit confused on the topic of sufficient statistics, and I am trying to understand the following.

I want to show that $\Pi_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i})$ is a sufficient statistic for $\alpha$ , which is unknown, where we have a random sample from distribution with density function

$$f(x)= (\alpha+1)x^{\alpha}$$ for $x \in (0,1)$ ,and $0$ otherwise

I just calculated the joint density to be

$$(\alpha+1)^{n} (\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}))^{\alpha}$$

Now from what I know, for something to be a sufficient statistic, we want to factor it as a function depending only on the sufficient statistic and $\alpha$ and one only depending on the x, which can be 1.

Is what I wrote above simply enough to show that, ie what I wrote above is the part depending on the product of the X and $\alpha$, times an identity function and thus I have shown it is a sufficient statistic?

Moreover I want to find the MLE and see if it is based off the sufficient statistic in order to conclude if it is or is not an MVUE. I compute the log likelihood and solve for $$\alpha= \frac{-n}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln X_{i}}-1$$

Now is that the only possibility? Or can I remove the $-1$ to clean it up?

My thoughts about this would be, if the product of the X was sufficient then the reciprocal of the sum of $\ln(x)$ would also be? And thus the MLE is based of a sufficient statistic and so is MVUE? Ie, I am a bit confused on what we can do to a sufficient statistic to have it remain one, etc,

Anyway, I am looking to see if anyone can help me go over this. Is it correct? Does it make sense? And do you have any advice or comments about it. Mostly I am still confused about the minus one, it seems to complicate things. Further, is any one to one function from a suffecient also suffecient?

Thank you

Comment: $\ln \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ or  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln X_{i}$?

Comment: Your proof that the product of the data is a sufficient statistic is right. You're also right that the reciprocal of the logarithm of this product is also a sufficient statistic. I don't understand how you arrived at the last displayed equation. What's $\theta$? Even assuming it was meant to be $\alpha$, I don't see how you got it.

Comment: Sorry meant \alpha, how I arrived is, I took the log likelihood function and took its first derivative then I set it equal to zero.

Comment: And i dont get what to do with the negative one

Comment: There's an edit button under the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely clear about showing sufficiency, you should write the joint density in the form $$f(\boldsymbol x \mid \alpha) = h(\boldsymbol x)g(\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) \mid \alpha),$$ and specify the functions $h$, $g$, and $\boldsymbol T$.  in your case, $\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) = T(\boldsymbol x)$, that is to say, your sufficient statistic for $\alpha$ is scalar-valued.  Your computation of the joint density is incomplete:  you must include the fact that observations are restricted to the interval $(0,1$): $$f(\boldsymbol x) = (\alpha + 1)^n \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^\alpha \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (0 < x_i < 1).$$  Note the use of the indicator function, which equals $1$ if the condition in parentheses is satisfied.  We can simplify the above as $$f(\boldsymbol x) = (\alpha + 1)^n \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^\alpha \mathbb 1 (0 < x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} < 1),$$ since the condition that each $x_i \in (0,1)$ is equivalent to saying that the smallest observation $x_{(1)}$ and the largest observation $x_{(n)}$ are in $(0,1)$.  Therefore, the choices $$h(\boldsymbol x) = \mathbb 1 (0 < x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} < 1), \quad g(T(\boldsymbol x) \mid \alpha) = (\alpha + 1)^n T(\boldsymbol x)^\alpha, \quad T(\boldsymbol x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$$ will satisfy the factorization theorem, and $T(\boldsymbol x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ is sufficient for $\alpha$.  Note how this is different than the $h$ you would have chosen with your calculation of the joint density.

---

The log-likelihood function is $$\ell (\alpha \mid \boldsymbol x) = n \log (\alpha + 1) + \alpha \log T(\boldsymbol x) + \log h(\boldsymbol x),$$ where for convenience, we express the log-likelihood in terms of the sufficient statistic  $T$ and the function $h$, rather than the sample $\boldsymbol x$.  Then the critical points for the log-likelihood satisfy $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{n}{\alpha + 1} + \log T(\boldsymbol x) = 0,$$ the solution of which is $$\hat \alpha = - \frac{n}{\log T(\boldsymbol x)} - 1.$$  Note that because we established the sufficiency of $T$ for $\alpha$, the MLE does not contain $h$, and it is a straightforward exercise to demonstrate that $\hat \alpha$ does in fact maximize the likelihood.  Observe that when $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in (0,1)$, $T(\boldsymbol x) \in (0,1)$, hence $\log T(\boldsymbol x) \in (-\infty, 0)$ and $\hat \alpha \in (-1, \infty)$, as desired.

---

In regard to the UMVUE (uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator), you would first have to calculate the bias of $\hat\alpha$; if it is not zero, it can't be a UMVUE; some transformation may be needed.  This is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks this is a helpful way for me to remeber to make it clear, but my question also is in regard to the MLE

Answer (score 0):

Everything you did was right, including the argument that applying an injective function to a sufficient statistic again yields a sufficient statistic. Except you didn't fix the mistake that Henry pointed out: The logarithm should be inside the sum. Since you correctly maximised the likelihood, this is indeed the only maximum-likelihood estimator, and since it depends only on the sufficient statistic, it is indeed a minimum-variance unbiased estimator.

Comment: Thank you I will correct this , do you have any comment about the minus 1?

Comment: @Quality: I don't. It looks right. I don't quite understand why you're unhappy about it.

Comment: The reason is because the book ( Mathematical Statistics with Applications) gives the same answer but without the -1

Comment: @Quality: That information should have been included in the question. "to clean it up" doesn't indicate that you have reason to believe that it's wrong.

Comment: Okay not sure I understand you now. The reason I have to believe it was wrong is that the sufficient statistic used in the book is different by an additive  -1 of mine, that is what I am trying to figure out